# Directory Handle Issue in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Netbeans (Apache NetBeans 12.0) says this line:

```
if ($dh = opendir($dir))
```

...produces an accidental assignment. It seems to think $dh is a variable and not the directory handle.

How do you correct this?

Additionally, NetBeans suggests "Change assignment to comparison
 ($dh === opendir($dir)

The code then fails. At least it worked with the ($dh = opendir($dir))!

Answer (score 0):

I did a [little](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=248237) [bit](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=147259) of reading, and it looks like older versions of netbeans might complain that you're assigning where there should be only a conditional statement.

Try refactoring to

```
<?php

$dh = opendir($dir);

if ($dh) { // ... etc
```

And since successful `opendir` funcitions return resources, you might even make the code clearer by doing `if (is_resource($dh))`.

Comment: I actually tried that before; it didn't change the message. This is the new release and maybe there is something buggy in Apache NetBeans 12.0. Or I may not fully grasp what the message is saying.